# Is it safe to use period symbols for fake MySQL database "namespacing"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to organize my ****load of MySQL tables into smaller sections, or namespaces if you will. Thus I would like to name my tables with namespace prefixes. I don't want to use underscores since I already use them for multi-word table names. Is it OK to use periods, or does that have a special meaning?

Example

```
CREATE TABLE `map.meta_data.updates` (...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use periods on your table name if they are quoted identified.

> **Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:**
>
> ```
> ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
>
> Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
> ```
>
> **Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode
>   Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:**
>
> ```
> ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
>
> Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
> ```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html#id807853

---

I personally prefer and advise to use only the permitted characters in unquotes identifiers!

Comment: Was about to post the same information. I'll just edit your question and add the link ;-)

Comment: Well I know it's 'allowed', but could it be a really bad idea? I always quote my database and table names anyway, so that's not an issue, But I know that MySQL names some files and folders in its data directory after database and table names, and I've had my MySQL installation on windows completely crash and stop working because I edited the case on some tables in PHPMyAdmin ("mytable" to "MyTable") and I was wondering if some similar oddities could occur with period symbols

Answer (score 4):

This is possible *if* you are prepared to ensure *every* identifier is delimited by back ticks

Personally, I wouldn't do this. I'd use `$` (if I had to) which is OK [without delimiters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: You mean like this? `SELECT * FROM \`map$meta_data$updates\` WHERE ...`?

Comment: @Codemonkey: More exactly: `SELECT * FROM map$meta_data_updates WHERE ... `. You don't require back ticks here and your "namespace" is separate from your multipart object name

Comment: Could that possibly introduce issues in PHP? I mean, substrings starting with `$` might be treated as if they were PHP variable names, might they not?

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by safe. It's not problematic to mysql, you may find it simply gets confusing - especially if you are not the only person using the db.

E.g.

```
select * from `map.meta_data.updates` where `table` = 'bar';
```

At a (late night, oh no, some problem, must fix) glance - is that the map db, meta_data table updates field and a typo?

Why not choose a character that doesn't already have meaning for mysql - $ if you want to avoid escaping - anything that isn't a period if you're happy to escape stuff.